# Yammer Embed with External Network - Sign-in issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, yammer-embed

How to auto-sign in to Yammer embed for external Network, placed on a SharePoint Online Site. Yammer Embed works Home network well (single sign-in work) on SharePoint Online Site, but not for External Network. It show sign-in control in yammer embed. For example, if I have two embed, one for home network and one for external network, the home network show the Yammer feed, but the other one ask to sign-in first.